# How to check if the OpenSSL version is -ge 1.1.1 in a shell script?

Tags: scripting, openssl, posix, version

My script requires OpenSSL 1.1.1 or newer for it to function.

Of course, the first steps are to get if OpenSSL is installed on that system, and if yes, then get the version of the default OpenSSL installation, like so:

```sh
command -v openssl
```

```sh
openssl version | awk '{print $2}'
```

To be honest, I don't have any idea how to check the version itself yet, will post my own answer if - and only if - the idea comes to me before you.

Please, adhere your answers to POSIX, away from Bashisms. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWK is part of POSIX, so this should be OK:

```
openssl version | awk '$2 ~ /(^0\.)|(^1\.(0\.|1\.0))/ { exit 1 }'
```

Instead of looking for versions greater than or equal to 1.1.1, this looks for versions less than 1.1.1: versions starting with “0.”, “1.0”, or “1.1.0”.

Comment: Yes, this also works with characters after the version number.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a bodge, but works:

```
export openssl_minversion=1.1.1
if echo -e "$(openssl version|awk '{print $2}')\n${openssl_minversion}" | sort -V | head -1 | grep -q ^${openssl_minversion}$;then
  echo okay
else
  echo nokay
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, yeah you're right you wouldn't need to `export` it. Also I don't think `sort -A` is POSIX either... This would work for any version number though rather than specifically `1.1.1`